# A Long double variable results in a negative number when a value is assigned

Tags: c, long-double

The issue I am having is that when I define a variable n as long double and set the value to 5 when i run it to print the value of n it prints -0.0000. I'm trying to achieve a larger range of numbers so i decided to switch from double to long double. 
OS: windows 10
IDE: Code blocks
compiler: mingw32-gcc.exe

```
long double n;
n=5;
printf("n= %Lf\n",n);
```

Comment: Try `n = 5.0;` -- `5` is an integer constant.

Comment: please try to use %lf, not %Lf.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @torstenvl That doesn't matter as the assignment will do the proper conversion from 5

Comment: @Jin: `l` in `%lf` has no effect (compared to `%f`); it would expect the argument to be `double`. It is inappropriate for `long double`. For `long double`, %Lf` is correct.

Comment: @Jin No, `%Lf` is the correct format for `long double`

Comment: Your code, as is, produces the expected result (e.g. `n= 5.000000`) on my system, so I am unable to reproduce the problem here (linux, fedora, gcc, glibc). What combo are you using?

Comment: Perhaps you're using a limited (smaller) version of `printf`. Do you have an option to use full version? What compiler, IDE, etc?

Comment: @CraigEstey I am coding this in code blocks.

Comment: @torstenvl I tried that, didn't seem to work.

Comment: @MrAlam : Code::Blocks is not a compiler.  Although you were asked about an IDE, that information is entirely irrelevant.  Compiler and target execution environment are important.

Comment: @FiddlingBits :  You need to be more specific than "_etc_" perhaps when asking for information?  Not sure why IDE would be relevant.

Comment: I just created a code::blocks project and it works here, too. What OS are you using (e.g. linux, WinX, MacOS) and what `libc` are you using (e.g. `glibc` under linux, or what under the other OSes)?

Comment: @Clifford Just trying to understand how compiler options are selected.

Comment: off topic to your question, but if you're "trying to achieve a larger range of numbers" and you have a factorial example in your screenshot, you probably want a multi precision library like GNU MP/gmplib

Comment: I am running this on Windows 10 and code blocks is using gnu gcc compiler to compile the code @CraigEstey

Comment: There is no need to post _pictures of text_.

Comment: You should be more specific - GCC version is required, and in particular you are likely to be using MinGW which uses Microsoft's C library rather then glibc.  Moreover the information should be in the question (edit it), not hidden in comments,

Comment: GCC uses the FPU's internal 80 bit representation for `long double`, while the Microsoft C library `printf()` used by MinGW uses 64bit because Microsoft'c compiler use a 64bit `long double` (i.e. same as `double`).

Comment: Your libc doesn't support `long double`. Consider either `cygwin` or: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab to download ubuntu under windows and use that

Comment: @CraigEstey: The problem is not that `long double` isn't supported. The problem is that the compiler (gcc) and the runtime library use different and incompatible representations for `long double`. Either representation would be perfectly legal as far as C is concerned, as long as the implementation uses it consistently. (There are ways to configure the implementation so it uses its own `printf` implementation that works correctly with gcc.)